# Switch sound to HDMI in Lubuntu without installing additional packages

Tags: sound, lubuntu, hdmi, alsa, lxde

Lubuntu doesn't use pulse audio, only ALSA. The only tools that come with it are alsamixer, alsactl, and aplay.

I have already managed to output sound from my TV using this command:

```
aplay -D plughw:0,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

How can I switch to HDMI without installing pulseaudio, or anything else, using only the tools that are already available out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the following entry into `/etc/asound.conf` or your `~/.asoundrc`:

```
pcm.!default = pcm.hdmi
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but I need to logout/login for the changes to take place, is there a command to reload the .asoundrc file? Preferably without requiring root.

Comment: The `.asoundrc` file is read by the ALSA library whenever a program opens some ALSA device the first time.